# Can't bake mesh texture as normal map w/o texture turning all purple

Tags: mesh, texturing, import, normals, roughness

I followed a tutorial by Ryan King Art on YouTube how to bake "realistic textures".
I was able to successfully bake a Roughness map, I believe a Diffuse map (#1 screenshot), but ***not* a Normal Map(screenshot #3).**
I had lowered the polys on my "feet" mesh (screenshot #1) when I imported it into this game and it's shown as some parts black. I feel like I know why but I've researched a lot and still haven't found what I was looking for.

Does anyone understand what I need to do to get rid of those black spots so it resembles the mesh I made in the first screenshot?
Thank you

**--To answer @moonboots question, I took another screenshot down towards the bottom of baking my low/high poly macaroon--**

[image: 1st picture]

[image: 2nd picture]

[image: 3rd picture]

[![4th picture][4]][4]

[image: To answer @moonboots question]

Comment: are you sure that the unwrap of the low-poly is correct? maybe share your file (only the high-poly and the low-poly objects), https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots I think it is correct.  I unwrapped both the low-poly and the high-poly meshes, marked seams, put the high-poly inside the low-poly, added the correct shaders with the image texture node to bake them and this is what I got... (I will add my screenshot to the bottom of my question cause it doesn't work here)

Comment: please share your objects, it will be easier to find the reason why it doesn't work  ;)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand how to share my objects? I could've sworn I did that by screenshotting, but I'm kinda new to Blender so maybe not lol @moonboots

Comment: share the blend file, only keep the high-poly and the low-poly object, then upload here and copy paste the URL it will generate: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I've tried everything to get the file size smaller but it doesn't allow me to without distorting the file itself. Is there another way to show you my meshes or is this the only way? @moonboots

Comment: you can send it to yourself with wetransfer and share the link

Comment: Thank you for all of your help so far lol.  I finally got it I think, here is the link https://wetransfer.com/downloads/322293580709fecf3b32c6b18d39b7d620220602064840/4dadf3c38d9cb3d49f1a54c301efc8f920220602064840/52358e @moonboots

Answer (score 0):

Apply the scale of both your objects, in the *feet* material create a new *Image Texture* node with a new *32-Bit Float* image, in the *Bake* panel choose an *Extrusion* of 0.3, bake. The result is not perfect probably because your feet material unwrap is completely shattered, maybe try to redo it.